# c: Python API - re-write value in the argument variable

Tags: python, c

There's a C function I want to wrap in the python package. However there's a constraint - instead of this C function to return anything, I need the result of a calculation to be written into the argument variable supplied to the function. Here's an example:

```
#include <Python.h>
void mock_rep(int n, int *res){
    PySys_WriteStdout("LOLO %i", n);
    *res = n + 2;
}
```

Can Python API directly interface with the memory of `res` like an R API does (in the R code this function is called with `.C(func, args)`?
Or there's something fundamental I miss about the calling by reference in C?

Rest of the wrapper:

```
static PyObject* mock(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    int n;
    int res;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"ii", &n, &res))
        return NULL;
    //return Py_BuildValue("i",res);' //commented out
    return Py_BuildValue("");
}

static PyMethodDef mainMethods[] = {
        {"mock",mock,METH_VARARGS,"Mock func"},
        {NULL,NULL,0,NULL}
};

static PyModuleDef cmath11 = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "cmath11","Mock stuff",
        -1,
        mainMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_cmath11(void){
    return PyModule_Create(&cmath11);
}
```

Python:

```
from cmath11 import mock as mc

res = 10
n = 2
mc(n, res)
print(res)
```

I need output to be 4. So far I get 10.